# Removing certain lines in perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
while ($line = <IN>){
    ...
print OUT "$line";
print OUT1 "$line";
}
```

Here I am using a `while` loop to read the lines in my input file. I would like to remove lines that start with the symbol `%`. I would also like to remove the lines that don't start with `A`, `B`, or `C`. What function can I use?

Comment: Your double quotes around `$line` in the `print` statements are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you just want lines which start with `A,B or C`.So you can simply use

```
^[ABC].*$
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So for your answer I should write `$line = ^[ABC].*$` in my while loop?

Comment: @Adrian No. `next unless $line =~ /^[ABC]/;`

Comment: @vks Don't think that the `.*` is necessary

Comment: @Adrian you can select the line you want and write them instead of deleting